# Elasticsearch how add parameterized conditions to filter term

Tags: elasticsearch

**Overall:**

- I'm new in Elasticsearch and trying to write a query with conditional term.
- *Parameter:* param_siteId
- *Condition:* considering the siteId in case of passing nonempty siteId param and ignoring the term clause in case of empty or null values.

**Current Query:**

```
{   "size" : 0,
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            {"term" : {"siteId" :   "{{param_siteId}}"}}
        ]
    }
}}
```

I tried scripting as well but my script was wrong. So I would be grateful if you could share your solutions with me.

Comment: What client are you using? This should be simple if statement on the client side unless I'm missing something

Comment: I'm gonna try it within kibana to see the result. In the meantime I'm using TransportClient from java to search on elasticsearch